# Can I program a microcontroller by manually programming an EEPROM and then coyping the EEPROM contents to the microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, eeprom

If so , what do I need to  learn in order to do that? 
I know it is  possible to manually program an EEPROM. But What I want to know is how I can  transfer the date stored in a eeprom to the microcontroller. I want to program the microcontroller manually. (Using dip switches and logic gates). I know some microcontrollers can't be  programmed without a computer interface. Which CAN be programmed without a computer interface? 
 Have a nice day.

Comment: What you might need to learn depends entirely on what you currently know and, given that your profile says "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them" nobody can tell except you.

Comment: "I want to program the microcontroller manually. (Using dip switches and logic gates)." Why? Do you have any other criteria for microcontroller choice, size architecture packaging etc? Would you accept a bootloader-based solution?

Comment: e.g. http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf - certain ST devices can boot  from an external SPI EEPROM.

Comment: How on earth can you program an eeprom with "dip-switches and logic gates"? Rather sounds as if you are merely using some manner of bootloader application written in firmware. It's like saying "I know that it is possible cook food by only using my voice, by telling my wife to cook it for me". Someone else is doing the actual work.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: @JardelB What EEPROM? What Microcontroller? "Is it possible?" questions are too broad. Ask specific questions to get good answers

Comment: You can indeed program a parallel E/EE PROM with switches and a pulse generator.  But to then copy the contents into a modern MCU would require something akin to a custom bootloader or self-flashing routine on the MCU.  At that point, you might as well just write one to accept direct input, much like front panel switches on early mainframes.  But computers are not hard to come by today, so why not use a scheme which accepts input (with all your entry mistakes pre-corrected) from one?

Comment: @Lundin - one can, in fact program parallel EPROMs and presumably EEPROMs with just switches to setup the address and data and a one-shot to generate a 50 ms write pulse.  And back in the day, there were people desperate enough to do so.   If one *had* a computer, wiring an 8255 (or discrete latches) into the bus and using that to drive the EPROM being loaded made a lot more sense.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No it has never been possible with "just switches and gates". Those memories required separate high voltages on certain pins, sometimes external clocks and sometimes various mumbo-jumbo ("pull pin x high when pin y is already low but only at full moon"). You'd end up with a custom PCB.

Comment: @Lundin - sorry, but you are very misinformed, as it really is this simple for classic 2716, 2764, 27128 etc EPROMs.  You use a switch to apply VPP, switches to setup the address and data, and you use a one-shot to deliver the programming pulse.  Clock?? **these parts don't have a clock**.  The only hard part is not making data-entry mistakes, which is why it's a lot more sensible to let a computer twiddle the bits.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I admit I wasn't around on the older stone age. During the younger stone age, before JTAG and similar, you programmed on-chip EEPROMs and data flash as I describe. And still you can't conjure the 25V programming voltage with "switches and gates". Getting a programming pulse between 45ms and 55ms might also be quite hairy without some form of clock - doing it with a capacitor only doesn't sound too professional.

Comment: @Lundin - getting a 25v VPP (I think mine only needed something like 12v) is not different in concept from getting a 5v *supply* rail.  I think I used a 555 for the pulse, they had a scope in the high school physics lab I used to check the timing.  "Professional" is a loaded word to throw around, in a way that ignores the existence of hobbyist built computers, the wide variety of  techniques developed there to limit tool costs, and equally the long history of precise *analog* computation which preceded digital techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you would want to program a microprocessor rather than a microcontroller in the way you describe.  By having the program storage external to the device, you have access to program it with an arrangement of switches and logic.  Static RAM would probably be simpler than EPROM if you're trying to keep external computer tools out of the equation.

I was surprised to see that some company is making the silicon that powered the original Apple.  Seven bucks mail order.  That would be one candidate.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty µCs still available that are based on intel 8031/8051. Many of them still support operation from an external EEPROM (`EA` pin).

EEPROM programming itself is not too simple using logic gates either. Most chips have specific timing requirements that your circuitry must obey for reliable operation. And one must not forget that buttons will bounce.